# Webflow CMS Slider + Lightbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, webflow

I am at a loss. I have created a CMS Slider + Lightbox on my CMS Projects Template page using the [Custom Image Gallery (Slider + Lightbox + CMS) by SketchzLab](https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/Custom-Image-Gallery-Slider-Lightbox-CMS). Everything works great until I want to show thumbnails under the lightbox by clicking on the "Link with other lightboxes" and assigning it a group name. When I do this, everything still works, except it populates double the amount of thumbnails. So, for instance it shows images 1,2, 3, 4 and then repeats this. So instead of 4 images it shows 8. It does this with every Project page. The slider though shows the correct amount of dots in the slider (4). Somewhere along the way, it is doubling the JSON array for the lightbox-strip div. I also noticed that this is the same outcome when clicking on the "Link with other lightboxes" and assigning it a group name and exporting the original cloneable site, so it is not something that I have done to my particular site, but rather a flaw on the original site. I have contacted the developer several times through various platform but never heard back from him. I would use another method if possible, but I have looked and looked and can not find anything like out there like it (CMS Slider AND Lightbox for Webflow).

Here is a [preview of the site](https://zervas-v14.webflow.io/projects/sedro-woolley-gateway-building-starbucks) with the particular page in question.

And here is a [read-only link of the Webflow project](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/zervas-v14?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=zervas-v14&preview=4c6d4cadf4ce0924c49de87dac11cb27&workflow=preview). The page in question is the "*Projects Template*" page.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

After I couldn't figure out why it was doubling the number of thumbnails, my next thought was to find the array that was being generated and then cut it in half like:

```
var newArray = OldArray.splice(0, Math.floor(OldArray.length / 2));
```

But when I did a console log on anything that I thought could represent this array, it always came back with the correct number (i.e. "4" instead of "8", etc.). So I am thinking that the array is just getting printed twice.